# How to intercept method calls in Unity (game engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aop, roslyn, interceptor

I have many types with many methods with the same signature and the same body in my project. all of them pack (serialize) their arguments, send them to the server, wait for the result, and unpack the result.

I think it's good to intercept method calls, get their argument, call common code, and inject the result.

I have done this successfully with Fody (MethodDecorator, MethodBoundaryAspect) and PostSharp in the .Net 6 app but none of them work in Unity.

I'm using Unity LTS 2022 and my target platform is Android but I plan to release IOS and OpenGL builds. my gist of the code is as below:

```
    public class UserHandler: Handler
    {
        public Task<(bool, string)> Command1((string message, int wait) data)
        {
            return Send<(string name, int avatarId), (bool, string)>(data);
        }

        public Task<string> Command2(int data)
        {
            return Send<int,string>(data);
        }
    }

    public class Handler
    {
        public string name;
        Server server;


        public async Task<TResult> Send<T, TResult>(T content, [CallerMemberName] string command = "")
        {
            byte[] bytes = await Packer.Pack(content!);
            bytes = await server.Send(name, command, bytes);
            return await Packer.Unpack<TResult>(bytes);
        }
    }
```